# Azure SQL | Create Stored Procedure | RequestError: Must declare the scalar variable

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

A quick one, I am trying to create a simple stored procedure (Azure SQL) with a parameter and I can't seem to find what's wrong with the code.

**Error**

```
[RequestError: Must declare the scalar variable "@TestF".]
```

**Code**

```
IF OBJECT_ID ( 'sampleSP', 'P' ) IS NOT NULL 
    DROP PROCEDURE sampleSP;
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE sampleSP 
    @TestF nvarchar(100)
AS     
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SELECT *
    FROM testT
    WHERE testF = @TestF;
GO
```

Comment: This runs fine on SQL 2014 on premises product. Are you sure this exact code reproduces the issue? +1 for executable repro code.

Comment: @usr yes, I am running the exact code using the npm tedious module

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. After all it was a problem with the npm module not executing 2 transactions at once!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The node.js module that you used to run this probably does not support the GO batch separator. SQL Server does not know what GO means. It's a client side concept. Remove it.